# Xamarin Forms Invalid property path syntax in Xaml when using OnPlatform extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am using the following syntax to determine property setting with in Xamarin Forms content pages:

FontSize="{OnPlatform Android=64, iOS=32}"

It was working, but I had to reinstall Visual Studio. After reinstallation every content page that uses this markup now shows the error: XLS0517 Invalid property path syntax.

Funny thing is it only occurs when the value is a number (int, double, etc...)
If I place a string value inside single quotes the error goes away. However a string of 32 will not work for HeightRequest.

Comment: I found a workaround for this, by adding UWP to the extension with a value of star or empty single quotes, the error goes away. (ex: FontSize=''{OnPlatform UWP='*', Android=64, iOS=32}")  Since I am not creating a UWP app this wont hurt anything, but it seems somewhat kludge.

Comment: Saw this when I upgraded from Xamarin Forms 3 to 5 in a StackLayout where I was using it to set Padding.  Adding UWP='*' made it go away for me as well.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue (ex: <StackLayout Padding="{OnIdiom '16', Desktop='0,0,0,10'}" Orientation="Horizontal">)

Comment: I have logged a bug with VS for this issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xaml-onplatform-binding-showing-warning-when-using/1392146). Please up this issue on Microsoft to get more attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks man... its work for me

Of: `Margin="{OnPlatform  Android='0,0,15,0', iOS='0'}"`

To: `Margin="{OnPlatform UWP= '*', Android='0,0,15,0', iOS='0'}"`

Answer (score 0):

More details in [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device) and a sample below:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             ....>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="test" FontSize="{x:OnPlatform iOS='14', Android='12'}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this issue by adding UWP='*' on the element.